# How to assign value to a pandas dataframe, when subset by complex index and boolean based conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I would like to replace values in a pandas dataframe, with a complex subsetting pattern.

With the .loc accessor, I was only able to subset by chaining multiple conditions, because some of the conditions are index based. But it seems I can not assign values after such a chain of subsetting.
**UPDATE:** A further problem is caused by the duplicated indicies. I have updated the example accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo'] * 10 + ['bar'] * 10, 'b': range(20)}, index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-01-10').append(pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-01-10')))

df.loc[df['a'] == 'foo', 'b'].loc[pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-05','2019-01-09'])] = np.nan

df
```

Result:

```
              a     b
2019-01-01  foo     0
2019-01-02  foo     1
2019-01-03  foo     2
2019-01-04  foo     3
2019-01-05  foo     4
2019-01-06  foo     5
2019-01-07  foo     6
2019-01-08  foo     7
2019-01-09  foo     8
2019-01-10  foo     9
2019-01-01  bar     10
2019-01-02  bar     11
2019-01-03  bar     12
2019-01-04  bar     13
2019-01-05  bar     14
2019-01-06  bar     15
2019-01-07  bar     16
2019-01-08  bar     17
2019-01-09  bar     18
2019-01-10  bar     19
```

Expected:

```
              a     b
2019-01-01  foo     0
2019-01-02  foo     1
2019-01-03  foo     2
2019-01-04  foo     3
2019-01-05  foo     NaN
2019-01-06  foo     5
2019-01-07  foo     6
2019-01-08  foo     7
2019-01-09  foo     NaN
2019-01-10  foo     9
2019-01-01  bar     10
2019-01-02  bar     11
2019-01-03  bar     12
2019-01-04  bar     13
2019-01-05  bar     14
2019-01-06  bar     15
2019-01-07  bar     16
2019-01-08  bar     17
2019-01-09  bar     18
2019-01-10  bar     19
```

I have tried alternative approaches like:

```
df.loc[df['a'] == 'foo' and df.index.isin(['2019-01-05','2019-01-09']), 'b']
```

which drops:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Not even this works, as the isin returns an array without the date based indexing:

```
df['a'] == 'foo' and pd.Series(df.index.isin(['2019-01-05','2019-01-09']))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with one `.loc` chain of `loc` assignment will be not safe

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(['2019-01-05','2019-01-09'])&df.a.eq('foo'),'b']=np.nan
```