# How to apply a function to a column given values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function and want to create a new column df['growth_factor'] which will have the derived value in it. The tricky part is that there are two other columns which need to be passed in the function for every row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"city":["losangeles", "losangeles", "newyork"],
                   "beds":[3, 4, 4]})

def growth_factor(city,beds):
    if beds==3:
        if city == 'losangeles'      : return 45
        else: False
    elif beds==4:
        if city == 'losangeles'      : return 47
        elif city == 'newyork'       : return 50
        else: False
    else: False
        
The function should pass into the df and should looks like this:

df=
'city'      | 'beds' | 'growth_factor'
losangeles  |3       | 45
losangeles  |4       | 47
newyork     |4       | 50
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your function would return false for the `newyork` row so that seems a bit odd.

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085383/6692898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

choices=[45,47,50]

conditions=[(df['beds'].eq(3) & df['city'].eq('losangeles')),
            (df['beds'].eq(4) & df['city'].eq('losangeles')),
            (df['beds'].eq(4) & df['city'].eq('newyork'))]

df['growth_factor']=np.select(conditions, choices, default='False')
```

Output:

```
df
         city  beds growth_factor
0  losangeles     3            45
1  losangeles     4            47
2     newyork     3         False
```

Answer (score 3):

There are faster ways to perform this look-up, but here is a straightforward approach:

```
df['growth_factor'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: growth_factor(x['city'], x['beds']), axis=1)
```

As an alternative approach, you could put the info in the growth_factor function into a second data frame, and then join it to df (using pd.merge()).

Answer (score 2):

Here is just a time comparative not an answer. In this case the most flexible solution is @jsmart but @MrNobody33 provided the fastest one

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df =  pd.DataFrame({"city":["losangeles", "losangeles", "newyork"],
                    "beds":[3,4,4]})
```

## @jsmart's solution

```py
def growth_factor(city,beds):
    if beds==3:
        if city == 'losangeles'      : return 45
        else: False
    elif beds==4:
        if city == 'losangeles'      : return 47
        elif city == 'newyork'       : return 50
        else: False
    else: False
```

```py
%%timeit -n 1000 -r 10
o = df.apply(
    lambda x: growth_factor(x['city'], x['beds']), axis=1)
```

```
1.2 ms ± 18.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## @MrNobody33's solution

```py
choices=[45,47,50]

conditions=[(df['beds'].eq(3) & df['city'].eq('losangeles')),
            (df['beds'].eq(4) & df['city'].eq('losangeles')),
            (df['beds'].eq(4) & df['city'].eq('newyork'))]
```

```py
%%timeit -n 1000 -r 10
o = np.select(conditions, choices, default='False')
```

```
184 µs ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Which is **6.5x** faster.

## Extra

If you have a dataframe with 3.000 rows instead of just 3 things goes even better for the vectorial solution

```py
df = pd.concat([df for i in range(1000)], ignore_index=True)
```

### apply

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
o = df.apply(
    lambda x: growth_factor(x['city'], x['beds']), axis=1)
```

```
84.3 ms ± 3.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### vectorial

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
o = np.select(conditions, choices, default='False')
```

```
437 µs ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

which is **193x** faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tests and the comparison! +1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g_f = growth_factor(row.city, row.beds)
    #print(g_f)
    #insert the value into df
    row.growth_factor = g_f
```

You basically iterate over each row and call your function to get the growth_factor column value, and then you assign it to df.

Also, something I noticed, your function is returning False for newyork city value. You might want to check it once again.